# C# Image GetObject

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking at open source from a 3rd party and found:

```
this.BackgroundImage = (Image)resourceManager.GetObject("$this.BackgroundImage");
```

What does the "$this" mean and where can I find the BackgroundImage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [documentation for ResourceManager.GetObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963f81yd.aspx), `$this` doesn't have any special meaning. The whole string `"$this.BackgroundImage"` is just a tag that was applied to a resource on a form. This is typical of Windows Forms designers. Create a form, go to the properties window, choose the `BackgroundImage` property and select an image file on disk. Then open the form's .Designer.cs file and you'll see similar code.

Comment: To change the image location the only way to do it is though the designer view? The designer doesnt open up due to some bugs.

Comment: The image itself is saved in the form's `.resx` file. Unfortunately, I don't know a way offhand to update the images stored in a `.resx` file.

Comment: I dont see .resx anywhere in the project. Instead there is a .resouces file whose content looks like assembly. Maybe the image info is embedded somewhere in the .resources file?